# Impedance sensing technology with headphone extension cord

Tags: impedance, impedance-matching, input-impedance, headphones

I have a simple question and I've tried researching the topic but I don't understand the technology. My computer uses impedance sensing technology to set the impedance for headphones.  My situation is I have headphones and I use a (3 foot) 3.55mm audio extension cable between my headphones and my motherboard. My headphones are 64 ohms but for some odd reason it registers the impedance for my headphones as double at 120. I don't understand why this is happening. Is the external headphone cable confusing my motherboard?

My motherboard is https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-1x#kf and
I also found this link to the patent to similar technology. https://patents.google.com/patent/US20140003616A1/en

Comment: Maybe your headphones are broken, or cable, or there's a bad connector connection? Maybe measurement is inaccurate or does not work? What would be the purpose of being able to measure impedance anyway, what difference would it make?

Comment: Are your headphone when connected to your mobo able to generate a stereo image to your ears? Have you tried that test?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, sounds out of both sides and nothing is wrong on either side

Comment: @Justme what's even more weird is that when I plug my headphones directly into the motherboard the same graph shows an impedance of 600. I'm so confused I don't know how all that works. I'm trying to match the impedance from the motherboard to the headphones.

Comment: @JessicaM. But is it a full stereo image or just mono sounding. Test with a known good stereo image sound file and listen for left and right sound image differences..

Comment: @JessicaM. You should not match audio output impedance to headphone impedance. You want as low output impedance as possible, to any impedance headphones.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, headphones and amplifiers do not match impedance. Rather the source device is low impedance relative to the load. For example a good headphone output might be less than 1 ohm while headphones are at least 16 ohms.

The only purpose those impedance sensing circuits serve is to adjust the volume setting range. The manufacturer assumes that lower impedance means higher sensitivity and so disables higher volume settings if it detects low impedance. If it detects higher impedance it'll let you raise the volume higher. The idea is to avoid hearing damage and comply with regulations in some countries that limit maximum loudness.

With that in mind is the software showing a slightly higher impedance actually a problem?  It should result in you simply having slightly wider range of volumes.